# mount error when installed using snap

Tags: mount, snap

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed cloudcompare using snap following:

```
sudo snap install cloudcompare
```

However, I get the following error when trying to launch it:

```
$ sudo cloudcompare.CloudCompare 
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /home /tmp/snap.rootfs_AUR1hM//home: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any chance this is in a lxd container?

Comment: No, I am not running this inside a container.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact problem and was able to fix it using a bind mount instead of a symlink. In my case I had a symlink for my home dir to /data/home. Remove the symlink, then create an empty directory for the mount point;

```
rm /home
mkdir /home
```

Then edit your /etc/fstab and add the line;

```
/data/home      /home   none    bind
```

Then reboot or enter the following command and /data/home will be mounted to /home.

```
mount /home
```

After that the snap applications will work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in my case I once sym-linked to /var/log and forgot about it.

```
sudo snap install snap-store --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/log /tmp/snap.rootfs_kDlTmB//var/log: Permission denied)
```

was always my error when installing something with snap.
I did:

```
cd /var
sudo rm log
sudo mkdir -p log # now /var/log is no symlink any more!
```

then it worked!